# How to convert 2022-10-27T00:00:00.000+00:00 into a standard date in YYYY-MM-DD format

Tags: python

Can someone please explain how to convert this 2022-10-27T00:00:00.000+00:00 date string value into the YYYY-MM-DD format in python

output should look like this : 2022-10-27

can anyone please help me here

Comment: If it's already a string, you just need to shorten it.  Truncate the string to ten characters.  What is the difficulty?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a string just use

```
variableHoldingString[0:10]
```

Ref: [https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-get-first-n-characters-in-a-string/#:~:text=To%20get%20the%20first%20N,and%20end_index_pos%20as%20N%20i.e.&text=The%20value%20of%20step_size%20will,characters%20of%20the%20given%20string](https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-get-first-n-characters-in-a-string/#:%7E:text=To%20get%20the%20first%20N,and%20end_index_pos%20as%20N%20i.e.&text=The%20value%20of%20step_size%20will,characters%20of%20the%20given%20string).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your string is an ISO 8601 datetime string. In Python, the right approach to parse such a string is by using the `datetime` module:

```
from datetime import datetime

old = "2022-10-27T00:00:00.000+00:00"
dt_obj = datetime.fromisoformat(old)
new = dt_obj.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

print(new)   # <- 2022-10-27
```